# Base de datos muy pesada en Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

Buenas:
Tengo una base de datos, con una columna con 20000 registros, que irá en aumento. 
Al intentar conectarme en local, me da este problema:

```
[Mon Feb  5 10:42:12 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 
536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 200704 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\applook\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php on line 67
[Mon Feb  5 10:42:12 2018] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in C:\xampp\htdocs\applook\vendor\symfony\debug\Exception\FatalErrorException.php on line 1
```

¿Como puedo configurar Mysql y Laravel para que no haya problema de lentitud o esta clase de errores?
Ya que ya cambie memory_limit = 256M en php.ini

```
protected function createPdoConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options)
{
    if (class_exists(PDOConnection::class) && ! $this->isPersistentConnection($options)) {
        return new PDOConnection($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
    }

    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
}
```

Comment: 20000, no son muchos mas bien son pocos. Puedes mostrar el script donde te da el error. seguramente estes desperdiciando memoria.

Comment: Es dificil ya que es Laravel. He editado la pregunta para que se vea más claro.

Comment: Pero creo que no va a aclarar mucho.

Comment: No me refiero a que muestres el nucleo de laravel, mas bien con que controlador/metodo te da problemas, ¿o en todos te falla? Cuando te da el error ¿a qué ruta llamas y que controlador y metodos entran en juego?

Comment: Buenas. Ya solucione el problema. Me estaba intentando conectar a la base de datos del servidor, y por eso daba ese problema. Perdón por las molestias. Un saludo.